# Four properties of normal families

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a family of functions in $H(\Omega)$ the space of holomorphic functions, and suppose that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly in compacts.

(1) Let $\overline{D_r(a)}\subset \Omega$ be a disck of radius $r$ centered in $a$ and $f(z)\neq 0 \forall z \in \partial D_r(a)$. Then there is $n_0$ such that for every $n>n_0$ $|f_n(z)-f(z)|<|f(z)|$ $\forall z\in \partial D_r(a)$

Proof: I think it should follow trivially from $f_n\to f$. I think of it this way: $f$ is defined in a compact disk, therefore it reaches a minumum $M$. Take $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon < M$. Because $f_n\to f$ there is a $n_0$ such that $|f_n(z)-f(z)|<\epsilon \leq |f(z)|$.

(2) There is $n_0$ such that for every $n>n_0$ $f_n$ has as many roots as $f$ in the closure of $D_r(a)$.

Proof: Follows from (1) like this: If $z_0$ is a zero then $|f_n(z_0)-f(z_0)|<|f(z_0)|=0$ then $f_n(z_0)=0$

(3) If $f_n$ has no roots, then either $f$ has no roots or $f=0$.

Proof: Seems the contrapositive of (2), if $f$ had a root then $f_n$ would have roots.

(4) If $f_n$ is injective, then either $f$ is injective or constant.

Proof: I don't know how to prove this one... But I want to prove it by means of an example, this is, taking a non-constant nor ind injective $f$ and showing that $f_n$ cannot be injective. I haven't been able to figure out a function for this.

Comment: Is $D_r(a)$ supposed to be the closed or the open disk with radius $r$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Open, but it doesn't matter - there were some typos in (1). We consider $f $ in the boundary.

Comment: Right. That makes more sense, since otherwise part (2) would be silly. But for $f$ to be defined on $\partial D_r(a)$ we need $\overline{D_r(a)} \subset \Omega$. Only $D_r(a) \subset \Omega$ is not enough. (Aside: your muscle memory made you type $H(\Omega)$ instead of $\Omega$ there.)

Comment: And the condition ought to be $f(z) \neq 0$ for $z \in \partial D_r(a)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The condition $\overline{D_r(a)}$ is right. I mistyped that too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right argument for (1), but you haven't written it up correctly. Since $f$ is complex-valued, it doesn't make sense to say that $f$ reaches a minimum (on $\partial D_r(a)$). You need to take the modulus, $\lvert f\rvert$ is a real-valued continuous function on $\Omega$, hence it attains a minimum on the compact set $\partial D_r(a)$. By the hypothesis, this minimum $M$ is strictly positive. Then the uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ on compact subsets of $\Omega$ - in particular on $\partial D_r(a)$ - gives you that there is an $n_0$ such that $\lvert f_n(z) - f(z)\rvert < \epsilon$ for $n \geqslant n_0$. Which by your choice of $\epsilon$ implies the desired conclusion.

Your argument for (2) doesn't work. We only know $\lvert f_n(z) - f(z)\rvert < \lvert f(z)\rvert$ on $\partial D_r(a)$, not in the interior. Also, $\lvert f_n(z_0) - f(z_0)\rvert < 0$ is impossible. Part (1) gave us the premises of [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9's_theorem), which yields the conclusion.

Part (3) is not completely the contrapositive of part (2), but mostly. What is missing is that if $f$ is not identically $0$ [assuming that $\Omega$ is connected, otherwise insert "on any connected component of $\Omega$"], then it has only isolated zeros. For an isolated zero $a$, we can choose a positive $r$ small enough that the premise of part (1) holds, and hence part (2). Thus: if $f$ has zeros, but does not identically vanish, by parts (1) and (2) we know that $f_n$ has zeros for all large enough $n$. That the condition $f \not\equiv 0$ is necessary is easily seen by considering $f_n \equiv \frac{1}{n}$.

For part (4), suppose that $f$ is neither constant nor injective. Then there are $z_1, z_2 \in \Omega$ with $f(z_1) = w = f(z_2)$ and $z_1 \neq z_2$. By considering $f - w$ and $f_n - w$ in place of $f$ and $f_n$, we can assume that $w = 0$. Since $f$ is not constant, for all small enough positive $r$, we have $\overline{D_r(z_k)} \subset \Omega$ and $f(z) \neq 0$ on $\partial D_r(z_k)$ for $k = 1$ and $k = 2$. If we choose $r < \frac{1}{2} \lvert z_1 - z_2\rvert$, these two disks are disjoint. By parts (1) and (2), each $f_n$ has a zero in $D_r(z_1)$ and a zero in $D_r(z_2)$ for large enough $n$, so is not injective.